# How to sort data already fetched from database with jquery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Below is my query which fetches data with filters:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE subid IN (:key2) AND Poscode=:postcode2 AND pricing=:rate2");
    $statement->execute(array(':key2' => $key2,':postcode2'=>$postcode,':rate2'=>$rate));
 // $row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = array();
 while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {

     array_push($json, array("name" => $row['Name'], "id" => $row['PostUUID'],"rate" => $row['pricing'],"reputation" => $row['Reputation'],"plus" => $row['ReviewPlus'],"neg" => $row['ReviewNeg'],"weekM" => $row['week_morning'],"weekA" => $row['week_afternoon'],"weekE" => $row['week_evening'],"endM" => $row['weekend_morning'],"endA" => $row['weekend_afternoon'],"endE" => $row['weekend_evening']));
 }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($json);
```

This is my ajax

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
    var data = {
        "action": "test"
    };

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ajax2.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {

            $("#main_content").slideUp("normal",function(){

            //$(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data+"<br/>");
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

$(".the-return").append("<div class='inside_return'>Name:" + data[i].name + "<br/>Id:" + data[i].id + "Pricing:" + data[i].rate + "<br/>Reputation:" + data[i].reputation+"<br/>Review Plus:" + data[i].plus+"<br/>Review Negative:" + data[i].neg+"<br/><h1>Availability</h1>Week Morning:" + data[i].weekM+"<br/>Week Afternoon:" + data[i].weekA+"<br/>Week Evening:" + data[i].weekE+"<br/>Weekend Morning:" + data[i].endM+"<br/>Weekend Afternoon:" + data[i].endA+"<br/>Week Evening:" + data[i].endE+"</div>");
            //alert(data[i].name) 
        }



            });
        }
    });
    return false;


});
```

> Now I already have data displaying in a page with specified
>   filters,meaning he result must be tally with the subid, poscode and
>   rate collected from user input.
>
> I'm giving the user to sort the already fetched data by review, rank
>   and so on...It must be swift(ajax). But hw do I go about it? Can
>   anyone give an idea please.
>
> The result are not in table row forms but they are displayed in div
>   block per record.
>
> How can I use jquery to achieve this, say if user clicked on 'sort by
>   rank'.
>
> I have some idea: Instead of firing a new query to the db each user
>   sort, how can I loop trough the array of data received in json above
>   and just sort from there?

```
$('#rank').on("click", function(){ //how to sort here});
```

EDITED PART:

referring to this link:[Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

I'm trying something like:

```
var sort_by = function(field, reverse, primer){

   var key = primer ? 
       function(x) {return primer(x[field])} : 
       function(x) {return x[field]};

   reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;

   return function (a, b) {
       return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
     } 
}

// Sort by price high to low
data.sort(sort_by('rate', true, parseInt));

// Sort by city, case-insensitive, A-Z
data.sort(sort_by('Name', false, function(a){return a.toUpperCase()}));
```

But it's not working, can anyone help to??

Comment: Check out this link on how to sort json values. But this will get realy complecated when you bring in all the conditions... [sorting ajax json elemnts](http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-sorting-json-objects-in-ajax/)

Comment: @HarigovindR, thanks for the link, I'm trying something like this:homes.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price) } );..........but not working of course; just hsaring with you if you know how o sort this way throughout the result..

Comment: Would it be at all possible for you to pass along with the ajax query the sorting details? Like {field: id, order:DESC} ? It would really ease the process for you.

Comment: @Reasurria , you mean in the query like this? 
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE subid IN (:key2) AND Poscode=:postcode2 AND pricing=:rate2 ORDER BY Poscode DESC LIMIT 60");

Comment: @sherly Yes. Then you can build the query dynamically depending on the sorting details you sent to the script. So "Poscode" will be whatever you passed through. EDIT: of course this is out of the question of your data is going to be huge.

Comment: @Reasurria, I thought of it but it might be troublesome as I want to sort  by multiple type namely, rank, rate,review, gender and so forth...SO each time I have to fetch a different query data or is there any other effective way?

Comment: @sherly No I think you are right not to take this route then. It will become troublesome to get data you already have every time. I'll see if I can think of something to help you with the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This solution tries to use the built in sort.

```
// I assume in the code that there are 2 properties "name" and "rating".

// a and b are of the same type as the data
function ratingComparer(a, b)
{
   if(parseInt(a.rating) < parseInt(b.rating))
     return -1;
   if(parseInt(a.rating) > parseInt(b.rating))
     return 1;

   return 0;
}

function nameComparer(a,b)
{
    // Same thing as with rating except we do string comparisons with a.name
    // and b.name
}

//Sort by rating
data.sort(ratingComparer);

// Sort by name
data.sort(nameComparer);
```

See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort link. The section right above the Example section is especially relevant to your situation I think.

EDIT: I think the problem with your implementation is that the comparison function expects 2 parameters of the type to be sorted. You'll probably have to use a switch or something to choose the correct comparison function instead of having a dynamic one like you have tried to use.